# 00 honda accord ex 3.0 coupe fuel pressure problems

Tags: honda, fuel-system, accord, gasoline

My car was caught in the flood that we recently had about a week ago in west phx, az. My car starts, runs, but in the flood my car got water in the oil pan, tranny, so I gave it an engine flush treatment, changed spark plugs, changed engine oil, tranny oil, n thought I could change fuel filter withouth having to change fuel pump.  Not podsible! Anyhow my car starts, runs but runs like if trying to get or Its not getting any fuel pressure going through the gas line. Itll let me drive it upto 6 or 7 miles then when pressing gas car wont move especially if going uphill. What could be causing this to happen? What can I do that I havent done to fix this problem

Comment: I'm wondering if you didn't get water into your exhaust and therefor your catalytic converters are plugged. Does it feel like it will only allow the engine to rev to about 2000-2500 and then just want to not go any faster (in park/neutral)?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Paulster2, it's very probably that you have water trapped in your exhaust.  After it runs for a few minutes, is there any steam coming out of the tailpipe?  A little steam is normal after first start up but after the engine warms up it should stop.  If you have a never ending source of steam you can take apart the exhaust system and dump it out (or if you really don't care, poke holes in the low spots).

If you really think it's a fuel pressure issue you can buy a gauge at pretty much any auto parts store and check the pressure off the fuel rail.  It's also possible you have some water in your gas tank, and that's what's causing it to bog.  The solution then would be to siphon out the gas and put new in.

Answer (score 0):

Most auto part stores will loan enough tools to test what's wrong. Check your fuel pressure, your cylinder compression, and make sure your ignition system doesn't have water damage.

If there are any DTCs those would help pinpoint the exact problem also.